# Curl binary linking error: LNK1104: cannot open file myproject\externals\curl-7.71.1-win32-mingw\lib.obj

Tags: c++, curl, libraries

*First of all, yes: there might be duplicates of this question, but I think that the error related to this issue is connected to a specific problem around curl and how I handled the installation.*

*NOTE: (···) means either "Win32" or "Win64"*

**#A.1.1** My IDE: Visual Studio 2019.

**#A.1.2** My project directory structure:

```
── myproject
        ├── myproject
        │   ├── src
        │   │   ├── main.cpp
        │   ├── myproject.vcxproj
        │   ├── myproject.vcxproj.filters
        │   └── myproject.vcxproj.user
        ├── externals
        │   ├── curl-7.71.1-(···)-mingw
        │   │   ├── include [THE INCLUDE DIRECTORY] 
        │   │   ├── lib [THE LIB DIRECTORY] 
        │   │   ├── docs (···)
        │   │   ├── bin (···)
        │   │   └── (··· other files ···)
        ├── .git
        ├── .vs
        └── myproject.sln
```

**#A.2** I added the *curl binary 32 bit v7.71.1 (2020-07-01)* from https://curl.haxx.se/windows/

**#A.3.1** In my solution, I went to the project *'myproject' -> (Right Click) -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories* and added the following line:
**$(SolutionDir)externals\curl-7.71.1-(···)-mingw\include** for the proper config. and platforms  -> Apply -> OK

**#A.3.2**  I went to the project *'myproject' -> (Right Click) -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies* and added the following line:
**$(SolutionDir)externals\curl-7.71.1-(···)-mingw\lib** for the proper config. and platforms -> Apply -> OK

**#A.4** I added some code to test it out (taken from https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html) (see code):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
    
int main()
    {
        CURL * curl;
        CURLcode res;
        
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
            /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 L);
            
            /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            /* Check for errors */
            if (res != CURLE_OK)
                fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
            
            /* always cleanup */
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

**#A.5** In Visual Studio 2019 IDE, after pressing the "Local Windows Debugger" button with any configuration and platform, I get the following linking error in the "Error List" field:

```
LNK1104: cannot open file myproject\externals\curl-7.71.1-(···)-mingw\lib.obj
```

---

**#B.1** So then I tried the following: add "$(SolutionDir)externals\curl-7.71.1-win64-mingw\lib" for 64 bits and "$(SolutionDir)externals\curl-7.71.1-win32-mingw\lib" for 32 bits config. in the "Additional Library Directories", but I still get this same error.

---

Certainly, there is no **lib.obj** file in the path **myproject\externals\curl-7.71.1-(···)-mingw**, nor any .obj file in all the binary (used the search bar typing *.obj* and there was nothing). Moreover, in the
**lib** directory there are only two files: **libcurl.a** and **libcurl.dll.a**, which don't end in **.obj**, but I assumed that VS2019 would use them as if they were **.obj** files (after all, they are in the *include* folder).

**By the way, at first I tried to clone its git repo as a submodule and then build curl using its included "winbuild" tool, but I eventually preferred to download the official binary as It was easier.*

Comment: I think the problem is in your linker settings.

Comment: You will have to build the curl library under its folder, the libraries will be copied under the Lib directory. This is the path then your project will have to specify under the 'Additional Library Directories' (NOT 'Additional Include Directories'). It is easy to get confused between the two. One is for library files, the other is for header files exported by third party libraries.

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar After adding "$(SolutionDir)externals\curl-7.71.1-win64-mingw\lib" for 64 bits and "$(SolutionDir)externals\curl-7.71.1-win32-mingw\lib" for 32 bits config. in the "Additional Library Directories" I still get this same error. Besides, isn't curl built already? I actually thought I downloaded a built binary. _*By the way, at first I tried to clone its git repo as a submodule and then build curl using its included "winbuild" tool, but I eventually preferred to download the official binary as It was easier._

Comment: @ElJaviLuki - Most of the open source projects provide option of either downloading binaries or source code. Some binary packages do not contain public exports or libraries. The project page usually asks you to download and build the code explicitly. About curl : there is a demo here https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2018/03/13/using-curl-library-from-c-on-windows/#:~:text=curl%20is%20a%20project%20containing,wrappers%20on%20top%20of%20it. Last step - "Add the following static libraries to the list of Additional dependencies: libcurld.lib;curlcppd.lib;Crypt32.lib;ws2_32.lib;winmm.lib;wldap32.lib;"

Comment: I downloaded the curl git submodule into my repo to get the solution file in `...\curl\projects\Windows\VC15\curl-all.sln`, but there's only until VC15 (I have VC16). Anyway, after opening it (the .sln file), VS 2019 throws these errors (Go to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63071844/error-project-solutiondirexternals-curl-projects-windows-vc15-lib-libcurl-v) for further details):

Answer (score 1):

*Finally I decided to build libcurl from source, cloning 'curl' as a git submodule from https://github.com/curl/curl. (Although perhaps this solution works the same way for a binary).*

To set-up curl for VS 2019, I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@farhabihelal/how-to-set-up-libcurl-on-visual-studio-2019-a9fdacce6945

Please, be aware that in this tutorial, the x86 release build is only done, you can also build it for other configurations (release or debug) and other platforms (x86 and x64).

**Another ***VERY*** important** thing when setting the Additional Dependencies in  *'myproject' -> (Right Click) -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies* is to make sure that you are using *libcurl_a.lib* for **release** versions and *libcurl_a_**debug***.lib for **debug** builds (this last one is commonly forgotten because we use to copy the paths for all the configurations, be careful!). If you don't pay attention to this you could have this linking error again (LNK1104).